# Javascript - update all divs of the same class in a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update CSS for all divs (one by one) with a certain class using plain Javascript loop. Here it is:

```
    var timerCoinRow = 0;
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.coin-row');
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) 
    {
        timerCoinRow += 500;
        obj = rows[i];  

        setTimeout(function () 
        {

            obj.style.opacity = 1;

        }, timerCoinRow);

    }
```

for some reason it does not work. here is JQuery version that works fine but I need it in plain "vanilla" Javascript:

```
var timerCoinRow = 0;
    $('.coin-row').each(function () 
    {
        timerCoinRow += 500);
        var obj =$(this);
        setTimeout(function () 
        {

            obj.css('opacity', '1');

        },timerCoinRow,obj);

    });
```

When I place  `obj.style.opacity = 1;` outside the timeout - all divs are updated but simultaneously while **I need them to appear one after another with a pause of 500ms**. Please help - it's somewhere near but ....

Comment: `obj` is updated to the last `<div>` after the `for` loop finishes, so all `setTimeout` calls are going to only affect the last one. Use `let`, or the third `setTimeout` parameter, or a closure.

Comment: @Xurfox -  thanks a bunch, man!  "LET" has solved the problem. But, in case this question will be seen by others - what did you mean by "third setTimeout" and "or a closure" ? Thanks once again!

Comment: Closures are explained in the link, the third parameter (or any optional paramater after the second one) is explained in the docs for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).